# How to access .net reosuce inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I need to access the net resource key inside java script function.
Something like shown in below code, Any advice?

```
data.ajaxLoader = function () {
    var loadingMessage = //GetLodaingMessageString("resourcesKey");
};
```

Comment: something like `var loadingMessage = '<% =GetLodaingMessageString("resourcesKey") %>';`

Comment: Does not work, it is resulted in a string

Comment: yes ... the function is called GetLodaingMessage**String** I assumed the result would be a string ... what should it be? remove the two `'` - does it now work?

Comment: No it does not :)

Comment: so ... what does `GetLodaingMessageString("resourcesKey")` return?

Comment: It's just a dummy methiod, something that I need